# How to retrieve a certain number of records using GROUP BY and ORDER BY in SQL (postgres)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Consider a postgresql table with N number of columns. One column contains a binomial classification `[0 1]`. I want to Group data by this field, following the next syntax (I am using **psycopg2** for python and **pg** for nodejs):

```
SELECT dummy_field,
COUNT(*)
FROM __table__
WHERE q_id = '2F5543E89823'
GROUP BY dummy_field
```

This query returns for example: `[(0, 1606), (1, 6674)]` values. I changed the above syntax in order to include only the last two days based on `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

That would be:

```
...
AND date_field > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2 days'
GROUP BY dummy_field
```

However, I want to retrieve in a different query only the last 1000 records based on `ORDER BY date_field DESC LIMIT 1000`. Since select fields does not include `date_field` I get this error:

> column "**field**.date_field" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

In order to avoid this error, I followed this syntax:

```
SELECT dummy_field, date_field,
COUNT(*)
FROM __table__
WHERE q_id = '2F5543E89823'
GROUP BY dummy_field, date_field
ORDER BY date_field DESC LIMIT 1000
```

However is not what I want. I want to use COUNT(*) and GROUP BY dummy_field, considering only the last 1000 records when date_field is sorted in DESC way.

Is there an other alternative to approach this result? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Generally, you LIMIT it first, then GROUP/COUNT it

```
SELECT      dummy_field, COUNT(*) AS rows
FROM        (
                SELECT      dummy_field, q_id
                FROM        __table__
                WHERE       date_field > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2 days'
                            AND t.q_id = '2F5543E89823'
                ORDER BY    date_field DESC
                LIMIT       1000
            ) AS t
GROUP BY    dummy_field
ORDER BY    dummy_field;
```

I'm not very sure if you want the `q_id` inside or outside the `1000 LIMIT` criteria. But you can move it out to just above the `GROUP BY` easily to change the behaviour.